# SQL, PHP: when submit plus 1 in table_field specified from dropdown

Tags: php, mysql

Hi guys I have been looking around in many of the post in here regarding using php to plus 1 in a table_field specifed by a dropdown on the php page. I am very new to this so I just tried some things out to see if I could get it to work but for me this is not easy :)

So here we go.
as you can see in the code there is a drow down that fetch data from a member table. In this table there is a field "isMcount" when a person have chosen a member from the drop down and then press submit I need it to +1 in the "isMcount" column for that specified member which is active in the drop down
Hope you will help.

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $row1 = $row['username'];
    $mc = $row['isMcount'];
    $row1 = mysql_real_escape_string($row1);
    $mc = mysql_real_escape_string($mc);
    
    
    mysql_query("UPDATE members SET isMcount = isMcount + 1 WHERE $row1 = username");
    $_SESSION['success'] = 'Page Updated';
    header('Location: '.DIRADMIN);
    exit();

}

?>
<select name="owner">
<?php 
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM members");
while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
echo "<option value=\"owner1\">" . $row1['username'] . "</option>";
}

?>

</select>
<form method="post"><input type="submit" name="owner" value="submit"/></form>
```

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: I have rolled this question back to the first version. Subsequent versions changed the names of HTML form fields, and the last one or two added the fix, which overwrote the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have wrong HTML part. Try option below. "username" is field name for select and will be available on $_POST['username'] with a value of username for your user.

```
<form method="post">
<select name="username">
<?php 
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM members");
while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    echo "<option value=\"" . $row1['username'] . "\">" . $row1['username'] . "</option>";
}

?> 
</select>
<input type="submit" name="owner" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

And you can remove isMCount from $_POST in PHP as you don't need it.

And then you update query would be:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE members SET isMcount = isMcount + 1 WHERE username = '" . $row1 . "'");
```

Comment: I tried it out still nothing
(the connection to the database is working the echo is showing values from the table

Comment: That's because you have $row1 = $_POST['owner']; instead of $row1 = $_POST['username']; inside your if statement.

Comment: Note to readers: the update operation here looks like it has a SQL injection vulnerability in it.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the statements within if condition:

```
 $row1 = $row['username']; // It should be $_POST['owner']
 $mc = $row['isMcount']; // You don't even need this

 mysql_query("UPDATE members SET isMcount = isMcount + 1 WHERE $row1 = username");
```

You simply need to get the username from the POST data submitted through the form.

So, you query should be something like this:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE members SET isMcount = isMcount + 1 WHERE username = '".$row1."' ") or die(mysql_error());
```

Also, you should change your HTML to this:

```
echo "<option value=\"" . $row1['username'] . "\">" . $row1['username'] . "</option>";
```

Hope this helps.

Peace! xD

Comment: You forgot to edit HTML part where select box was completely out of form part.

Comment: Yeah, just noticed that, lol. I've fixed it, though. it should work just fine.

Comment: ok I cleaned it up and tied the things our still no luck 
(i updated the code)
the echo is working :)
btw I already checked it the connecting is working with another script and there is no problem there

Answer (score 1):

Some suspected areas are in your code

```
<form action="#" method="POST">
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $username = $row['username'];
        $mc = $row['isMcount'];
        $row1 = mysql_real_escape_string($row1);
        $mc = mysql_real_escape_string($mc);
        mysql_query("UPDATE members SET isMcount = isMcount + 1 WHERE username = '$username'");
        $_SESSION['success'] = 'Page Updated';
        header('Location: '.DIRADMIN);
        exit();
    }
?>
<select name="username">
<?php
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM members");
    while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        echo "<option value='".$row1['username']."'>".$row1['username']."</option>";
    }
?>

</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

**Suggestion : Use mysqli or pdo instead of mysql**

Comment: Your select box is still outside form area.

Comment: have added now, but still here deprecated mysql code is exist , which we dont recommended

Comment: hi thanks for the answer
about the mysqli vs mysql is this important for security reasons?

Comment: Yes it is very important, check here how to use mysqli : http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/03/basic-php-mysqli-usage